# NestJS: MongoDB Aggregate gives error with pipeline

Tags: database, mongodb, api, nosql, nestjs

So, when i add a **pipeline** function in my **aggregate** then its gives me this error:

[image: error]

**Heres my code:**

```
    let rqs: any = this.friendrequestModel.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "author",
          foreignField: "_id",
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                friend_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userid)
              }
            }
          ],
          as: "userdata",
        },
      },
    ]);
```

Comment: The error is JS based, it is not originating from MongoDB. Please add more code, if you need help.

Comment: This might be a case when the author's id from localField is saved in a string instead of ObjectId